# Traversing binary search tree, how to advoid code duplication

Tags: c, function, binary-search-tree, traversal, code-duplication

I have been working on this small program. It reads data(members) from a file and stores it in a binary search tree. There are two features, print all the members and print all members but only with the same boat class. To achieve this it traverses the tree.

```
void traverse_tree(member_node member, void(*print_members)(member_node)) {

        print_members(member);

        if (member->left != NULL) {
            traverse_tree(member->left, print_members);
        }

        if (member->right != NULL) {
            traverse_tree(member->right, print_members);
        }
    }

void list_by_boat_class(member_node member, char *boat_class, void(*print_members)(member_node)) {

    if (strcmp(member->boat_class, boat_class) == 0) {
        print_members(member);

    }
    if (member->left != NULL) {
        list_by_boat_class(member->left, boat_class, print_members);
    }
    if (member->right != NULL) {
        list_by_boat_class(member->right, boat_class, print_members);
    }
}
```

Struct def:

```
typedef struct member * member_node;

typedef struct member{
    char name[NAME];
    char personal_names[PERSONAL_NAMES];
    int mem_id;
    char email[EMAIL];
    char boat_class[BOAT_CLASS];
    char boat_name[BOAT_NAME];

    struct member * left;
    struct member * right;
}member;
```

The traversing seems like a code duplication to me. I tried to merge these functions in to one but each function takes different arguments. Is there any solution to this or it has to stay separated?

Comment: Please avoid including the `*` in the typedef. It's very important to know whether something is a pointer or not. This should not be hidden from your readers.

Answer (score 2):

Move the check into the visitor, and have the visitor accept an extra argument passed to `traverse_tree`.

```
void print_member(member *member, int depth, void *data) {
    ...
}

void print_member_of_boat_class(member *member, int depth, void *data) {
    const char *boat_class = data;
    if (strcmp(member->boat_class, boat_class))
        return;

    print_member(member, depth, NULL);
}

void traverse_tree(member *member, int depth, void (*visitor)(member*), void *data) {
    visitor(member, depth, data);
    ++depth;
    if (member->left)
        traverse_tree(member->left, depth, print_members, data);
    if (member->right)
        traverse_tree(member->right, depth, print_members, data);
}

traverse_tree(tree, 0, print_member, NULL);

traverse_tree(tree, 0, print_member_of_boat_class, boat_class);
```

Passing a node's depth to the visitor is often useful, so I added that too.

Comment: Shame c does not have closures

Comment: @Ian Ringrose, aye. I was trying to find a way of mention that without making things too complicated

Comment: It like explaining the Tesla Model 3 to someone who has only experienced hourse powered transport.